# How can I change the compiling dir of hlsl files using CMAKE?

Tags: cmake, hlsl

I am using CMake 3.9.1, and I am already changing my project RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY to a different folder.

However, I want to change the output of hlsl files(cso).

Comment: ... How are you compiling them now? If you have a `custom_command` for them changing the output directory is trivial, no?

Comment: VS will automatically compile the hlsl files.  Problem is I can not find any information on how to change the hlsl compiling output dir.

Comment: @Botje Shouldn't there be some command to change the hlsl output dir?  How does custom_command work?  Will it run a script right AFTER the the VS solution is built, and BEFORE it executes?  I dont think that is possible...

Comment: How is CMake related to VS in this situation? Did you create a project and add the hlsls files to a target using `add_executable` ? Did you just drag the files into a VS project generated from a CMake file? That was what I meant with my first question.

Comment: @Botje Yes.  I add it to the add-excutable

Comment: It looks like the `<FxCompile>` target in the resulting MSBuild just dumps everything in `$(IntDir)`, without much option to change it. sorry

Comment: @Botje Thank you.  Is there any hacks that can be used?  Like maybe changing the name of the file with CMAKE to add "../../somedir/somedir/.*hlsl"?

Comment: you could add a `POST_BUILD` custom command to your target to copy or move the compiled files to where you want them to go.

Comment: It will run the POST_BUILD after visual studio generates the cso files in $(IntDir) folder, and before VS runs the program during debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for CMAKE 3.9.1 visual studio

```
add_custom_command(TARGET ${projectName} POST_BUILD COMMAND cmd /c ${PROJECT_CONFIGURATION}/shadercopy.bat)
```

It will run the .bat right after visual studio builds the project and right before it executes!